# Get Date Counts Based on a Parameter in PowerBI if Data is in one table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm stuck in this peculiar issue.
I want to get Counts/Visualization of Different Columns which all have dates based on a Parameter but the data is in a single table.

Here is an example -

Data -
[image]

Let's consider this as a parameter/Filter that'll filter the data this should be independent of the data so we can give it a range of Min and Max of dates of all columns A, B, and C and it should have all the Months in Series -

[image]

So when I select March it should return the counts of March as and all the visualization should also only show March counts-

[image]

I'm confused about what will I use as the X-Axis in Visualization so it remains independent of the columns.

EDIT -

| Unique ID | Entry Date | Division | Region | OrderDate | Delivery Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-02-2023 | West | WB | 02-Sep-23 |  |
| 2 | 2/30/2023 02:55 | West | DEL | 02-Sep-23 | Oct-23 |
| 3 | 2/30/2023 02:56 | East | HAR |  | Sep-23 |
| 4 | 2/30/2023 02:57 | Central | WB | 02-Sep-23 |  |
| 5 | 2/30/2023 02:58 | Central | DEL |  |  |
| 6 | 2/30/2023 02:59 | East | HAR | 02-Sep-23 |  |
| 7 | 2/30/2023 02:60 | East | WB |  |  |
| 8 | 2/30/2023 02:61 | Central | DEL | 03-Oct-23 |  |
| 9 | 2/30/2023 02:62 | East | HAR |  |  |
| 10 | 2/30/2023 02:63 | East | WB | 21-Oct-23 |  |
| 11 | 2/30/2023 02:64 | Central | DEL |  |  |
| 12 | 2/30/2023 02:65 | Central | HAR | 21-May-23 |  |
| 13 | 2/30/2023 02:66 | Central | WB | 21-May-23 |  |
| 14 | 2/30/2023 02:67 | Central | DEL | 21-May-23 | Aug-23 |
| 15 | 2/30/2023 02:68 | Central | HAR | 21-May-23 | Aug-23 |
| 16 | 2/30/2023 02:69 | Central | WB | 21-May-23 |  |
| 17 | 2/30/2023 02:70 | East | DEL | 21-May-23 |  |
| 18 | 2/30/2023 02:71 | East | HAR | 21-May-23 | Aug-23 |
| 19 | 2/30/2023 02:72 | Central | WB | 21-May-23 | Aug-23 |
| 20 | 2/30/2023 02:73 | East | DEL | 21-May-23 |  |

Expectation -

All the column chart using the above dates should give count based on the month selected in the parameter.
I've filter for division and Region applied as well they should also filter the count.

Comment: Paste your data as a copiable table rather than an image

Comment: Is your data like the one above, with just those three (A, B, C) columns or do you have more columns in your actual data model? Your life would be so much easier if you un-pivot your data so that you have columns `Index | Attribute | Value` with an example row of `1 | A | March`

Comment: Sorry, Just added a sample table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a Date Table. You can create an example of one with these steps:

1. Create a Calculated Table (via `New Table` under the `Modeling` tab in the ribbon) with the following:

```
DateTable = 
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Month", FORMAT([Date], "MMM"),
    "MonthNum", MONTH([Date]),
    "Year", YEAR([Date]),
    "Year-Month", FORMAT([Date], "yyyy-MM")
  )
```

2. Once created, click on the `Month` column in the `DateTable`, then `Sort by column` in the ribbon, and select `MonthNum`. This will ensure Jan, Feb etc... will be ordered correctly.
3. Right-click on `DateTable` and select `Mark as date table` and in the pop-up select `Date` as the Date column.

That's your date table created. Next we need to add relationships to your data table.

But first, your `Entry Date` column is Date Time data type, so we need a Date version of this:

- Create a new column in your data table with:

```
Date = DATEVALUE(FORMAT([Entry Date], "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Now to add the relationships. Switch to `Model view` (third button/icon down on the far-left vertical toolbar). You should see your two tables.

- Click'n'drag the `Date` from your **data table** to the `Date` in the `DateTable`.
- Do the same for `OrderDate` and `Delivery Date`.
  You should have one active, and two inactive relationships, looking like:

[image]

Now you can create Measures based on the above:

```
ID Count = DISTINCTCOUNT(YourDataTable[Unique ID])

ID Count by EntryDate = [ID Count]

ID Count by OrderDate = CALCULATE([ID Count], USERELATIONSHIP(DateTable[Date], YourDataTable[OrderDate])

ID Count by DeliveryDate = CALCULATE([ID Count], USERELATIONSHIP(DateTable[Date], YourDataTable[Delivery Date])
```

Finally, for your chart:

- Add `DateTable[Month]` to the X-axis
- Add `ID Count by EntryDate`, `ID Count by OrderDate`, and `ID Count by DeliveryDate` to the Y-axis

---

**Additional**

To have interactive charts that update cards with the relevant counts, then you'll need the following:

1. Create a new Calculated Table to your model with the following:

```
Date Role = DATATABLE("Role", STRING, { {"Entry"}, {"Order"}, {"Delivery"} } )
```

2. Create a new Measure with the following:

```
Date Role Count = 
  var eRole = CONTAINS('Date Role', 'Date Role'[Role], "Entry")
  var oRole = CONTAINS('Date Role', 'Date Role'[Role], "Order")
  var dRole = CONTAINS('Date Role', 'Date Role'[Role], "Delivery")

  var eValues =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT(YourDataTable[Unique ID]),
      NOT ISBLANK(YourDataTable[Unique ID]) = eRole
    )

  var oValues =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT(YourDataTable[Unique ID]),
      USERELATIONSHIP(DateTable[Date], YourDataTable[OrderDate]),
      NOT ISBLANK(YourDataTable[Unique ID]) = oRole
    )
  
  var dValues =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT(Sheet2[Unique ID]),
      USERELATIONSHIP(DateTable[Date], YourDataTable[Delivery Date]),
      NOT ISBLANK(YourDataTable[Unique ID]) = dRole
    )
  return
    COUNTROWS( DISTINCT( UNION( eValues, oValues, dValues) ) )
```

3. Update your charts to use `[Date Role Count]` in Values or Axis, and use `'Date Role'[Role]` for the Legend. Optionally, you can then filter for which "Roles" you want displayed in your chart (eg Order & Delivery).
4. For your card visual, use `[Date Role Count]` as well.

Comment: Thanks! Sam. This worked and I can't appreciate enough such a well-documented step-by-step solution.

Comment: Hey Sam! I'm facing this issue - The active relationship between DateTable[Date] - Entry Date. Now, in a column chart with X-axis - DateTable[Month] and Y-axis - ID Count by OrderDate, and ID Count by DeliveryDate. When I click a bar of September in the column chart the ID Count card shows counts of Unique IDs that fall in September (be it 2022 or 2023 ) even if the corresponding Order date/delivery date is Blank.

Comment: That sounds right, if I understood you correctly. What number do you want to see in the card? Unique count (without duplicates) of Order and Delivery of that month?

Comment: I want to see the count that each respective Viz/Chart will filter through. If I click on September on OrderDate in the Above Column chart (X-axis - DateTable[Month] and Y-axis - ID Count by OrderDate, and ID Count by DeliveryDate). The card with the count of Unique ID should show the count of OrderDates in September.

Comment: And what should it show if no selection is made?

Comment: If no selection is done then Total count, the default option.

Comment: And what if two selections are made, one for Order, and the other for Delivery?

Comment: A column chart with two bars for a single X-Axis unit usually doesn't allow two selections right? But if two are done It should show the total count of Unique IDs ( In Case a single Unique ID has both Delivery and Order Date then that should be counted as one only )

Comment: See updated answer, under the **Additional** section at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you! I learned so much from that amazing answer. Also, the clustered bars are individually filtering the counts which is amazing. The usual simple drag and drop columns usually only filter only one column.

Comment: Hey Sam! Is there a way to get a column chart with dynamic X axis? For eg. If I select March 2023 in the filter that column chart should show counts for all months till March 2023 with count of OrderDates? I'm currently doing it by duplicating the DateTable and using it till <Max(DateTable[Date]).

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve the above thing?

Comment: That is the way to do it. Ultimately, your slicer and chart axis need to be from different tables.

Comment: Hey Sam! I have a follow-up question for instance I've counts of 3 for the `Delivery Date` of March. How do I get the corresponding data (all columns in the above sample table) to show up in a table Viz which I can again switch based on the type Date selected i.e. ` Delivery Date` ,  `Order Date` , and `Enter Date` ? Hence, if I select `Delivery Date` on counts satisfying all filters, it should show up with the corresponding details in Table viz?

Comment: Hey Sam! Is there a way to do this above thing?